# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, gridview, kendo-ui

I'm new in using Kendo Grid and Kendo UI . My question is how can i resolve this Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

This is my Code on my KendoGrid

```
$("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
            },
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Info/InfoList?search=' + search,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST"
                    }

                },
                pageSize: 10
            },
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html().replace('k-alt', '')),
            altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html())
        });
```

Line that Causes the Error

```
rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html().replace('k-alt', '')),
```

HTML of rowTemplate

```
   <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">   
        <tr class='k-alt'>
            <td>
                ${ FirstName } ${ LastName }
            </td>
        </tr>
            </script>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: because `$("#rowTemplate").html()` returns undefined

Comment: is there an element with id `rowTemplate` in your page

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeah. wait ill just update my question

Comment: can you do `alert($("#rowTemplate").length)` before `$("#Grid").kendoGrid({..});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny sir it alerts `0` what should i do next? also checked the naming of id's but all of them is unique

Comment: whether your js code is in a dom ready handler? if not move it to a dom ready handler and check again

Comment: @ArunPJohny sir already in Document ready handler but same result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError : cannot read property 'replace' of undefined In Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354554/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-in-grid)

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery cannot find the element.

First of all find the element

```
var rowTemplate= document.getElementsByName("rowTemplate");
```

or

```
var rowTemplate = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
```

or

```
var rowTemplate = $('#rowTemplate');
```

Then try your code again

rowTemplate.html().replace(....)

This question is already available in:
[Uncaught TypeError : cannot read property 'replace' of undefined In Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354554/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-in-grid)