# Uncaught TypeError : cannot read property 'replace' of undefined In Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm new in using Kendo Grid and Kendo UI . My question is how can i resolve this Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

This is my Code on my KendoGrid

```
$("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
            },
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Info/InfoList?search=' + search,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST"
                    }

                },
                pageSize: 10
            },
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html().replace('k-alt', '')),
            altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html())
        });
```

Line that Causes the Error

```
rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html().replace('k-alt', '')),
```

HTML of rowTemplate

```
 <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">   
        <tr class='k-alt'>
            <td>
                ${ FirstName } ${ LastName }
            </td>
        </tr>
            </script>
```

Comment: the only reason I can see is that jQuery is not able to find the element with id `rowTemplate`... can you log the value of `$("#rowTemplate").length` and see what is returned

Comment: @ArunPJohny it returns 0

Comment: that is the reason... there are no element with id `rowTemplate` in your page

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think jQuery cannot find the element.

First of all find the element

```
var rowTemplate= document.getElementsByName("rowTemplate");
```

or

```
var rowTemplate = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
```

or

```
var rowTemplate = $('#rowTemplate');
```

Then try your code again

```
rowTemplate.html().replace(....)
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be because of the property `pageable -> pageSizes: true`.

Remove this and check again.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onDataBound(e) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            $(grid.tbody).find('tr').removeClass('k-alt');
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                Freight: { type: "number" },
                                ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 20,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },
                height: 430,
                filterable: true,
                dataBound: onDataBound,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "OrderID",
                    filterable: false
                },
                            "Freight",
                            {
                                field: "OrderDate",
                                title: "Order Date",
                                width: 120,
                                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                            }, {
                                field: "ShipName",
                                title: "Ship Name",
                                width: 260
                            }, {
                                field: "ShipCity",
                                title: "Ship City",
                                width: 150
                            }
                        ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have implemented same thing with different way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a View that I´ve converted to partial view and I forgot to remove the template from "@section scripts". Removing the section block, solved my problem. This is because the sections aren´t rendered in partial views.

Answer (score 0):

**It is important to define an id in the model**

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id))
    )
```

Comment: Please only english, do not add translation for other languages.