# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined or in kendo list view dynamic binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

hi i am using kendo list view in my code and want to dynamic binding with remote data source , and i want to bind the data on button click but its showing two error and not hitting on url but hitting on function, and url is also correct

```
  <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="" id="listView">
</div></div></div>

<script>
    function GuelsiderSearch() {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Gulesider/Search",
                dataType: "json",
                type:"GET"
            }
        },
    });

    $("#listView").kendoListView({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove the comma of `transport` object first, I'm not sure it is necessary or not. `transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Gulesider/Search",
                dataType: "json",
                type:"GET"
            }
        }`

Comment: Please post your "Search" action of your "Gulesider" controller.

Comment: Check this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354554/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-in-grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354554/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-in-grid)